# Javascript functions working only by explicit coding and not in a for cycle

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript code that works perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
  $("#Select1").setDefault();    
  $("#Select2").setDefault();     
  $("#Select3").setDefault();      
  $("#Select4").setDefault();   
  $("#Select5").setDefault();      
  $("#Select6").setDefault();   
});
```

Now, If I use the following compact code it doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for(i=1; i<=6; i++){
    $("#Select"+i).setDefault();    
  }
});
```

The **for** works fine if I write:

```
for(i=1; i<=6; i++){
    alert(i);    
}
```

Any idea?

PS: I use Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop code is missing the closing parenthesis... a `)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  for(i=1; i<=6; i++){
    $("#Select"+i).setDefault();    
  }
});
```

Using a developer tool like Firebug will highlight these syntax errors for you. If you're using Chrome hit F12 and you will have access to  JavaScript console, etc, etc...

Comment: Okay, why not put your code into a fiddle as we don"t know what your HTML is and we have to assume by the IDs you're working with Select Menus...http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Because it is a little bit more complicated. There are Ajax call to get a response from a Symfony Controller. jsfiddle accepts HTML, JS and CSS. Moreover, I get some libraries at rutmine (like JQuery)

Comment: "I get some libraries at rutmine (like JQuery)"... have a look at jsfiddle as you can include Frameworks and their version

Answer (score 1):

You could fix your existing code which uses a loop, however as an alternative and possibly cleaner solution, try using the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('[id^="Select"]').setDefault();    
});
```

Assuming you're using `<select>`s in your HTML (a guess from your IDs), you can make the selector a little more specific:

```
$('select[id^="Select"]').setDefault();
```

Comment: You are assuming that the for is wrong! Isn'it! Moreover, why `$("#Select"+i)` should be different by `$("#Select1")` when `i=1`?

Comment: "You are assuming that the for is wrong! Isn'it!" - please put this into a fiddle, we are trying to help!

Comment: I'm not assuming your loop is wrong, but offering a better solution to your example posted. You mention in a comment that you fire AJAX requests, so please post the _actual_ code you're having problems with; you may be encountering time issues due to the asynchronous nature of AJAX.

Comment: @Mike Agreed, how can anybody help anyone when they're blindfolded?

Comment: I know, I know! Thanks in advance. But the first answer by Mike Sav lead to a lot of misunderstanding, everybody is downvoting without focusing on the real problem!

Comment: You've been downvoted because you provide little detail in your OP. You've also said that there is an AJAX request somewhere, _yet you haven't posted the code for it_.

Comment: Well perhaps you should have put your real code into a fiddle before posting. I solved your original problem, which was due to you posting before reviewing. Why bother? I think I'll move on

Comment: Dear Mike Sav, I'm bothered since things evolved in the wrong way also after my update. However, I found the bug, but I can't solve it. In practice, just inside the `setDefault()` I did a print via `alert()` of the `id` of this element. It is null! Seems like that the element is not found within the DOM.